# Capturing packets on a certain ip

Tags: java, jpcap

Is it possible to create a java class using JPCAP that capture all the packets destined to a particular IP address?
Like if i need to capture all the packets destined to my router .. is it possible ?

Comment: do you mean destined to a particular IP?

Comment: exactly.. i need to only capture packets threw the router

Comment: In a network all packets pass "through" the router. Ideally

Comment: Why don't you just use and existing packet sniffer; e.g. WireShark.

Comment: he is willing to do it through jpcap

Comment: its my senior project and i must use JPCAP, and when i run the project the src ip is my ip and the dest ip is for example the server of google. It must give me the gateway!

Answer (score 0):

Yes It is..

- Packet capturing using jpcap (or any such library) allows the user to open the Ethernet interface in two different modes.
- In **promiscuous mode**, you can capture every packet from the wire, i.e., even if its source or destination MAC address is not same as the MAC address of the interface you are opening.
- In **non-promiscuous mode**, you can only capture packets send and received by your host.
- In order to catch all the packets passing through your router you need to tell your program to open the Ethernet interface in promiscuous mode.
- This will enable you to capture all the packets flowing in the network.Later you will need to **filter** these packets according to your router's IP address.

Comment: Your wright about the diffrent modes, but about the filtering, you  can't filter for ip addresses you can use the filter technique to listen for TCP/IP packets for example.

Comment: yes you can filter them at the time of capturing or after storing the captured packets in a file and then parsing the file